# What is the meaning of "have after"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Queen Elizabeth said this words to Duke, Who found in cross dresser.

> Although my affection for you is undiminished, l **have, after** an
>   agonizing struggle, determined to sacrifice my own happiness for the
>   welfare of my people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The have is an auxiliary verb, and this sentence can be rewritten in the following form:

After an agonizing struggle, I have determined to sacrifice....

The author has placed the preposition phrase after the subject phrase in this case, likely to break the repetition of dependent clauses.